# Smooth functions into infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, smooth-functions, schwartz-space

I am currently working with infinite-dimensional (separable) Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and functions of the type
\begin{align}
f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathcal{H}.
\end{align}
What does it mean for $f$ to be smooth? Is is sufficient to show that

1. $x\mapsto (\Phi,f(x))$ is smooth for all $\Phi\in\mathcal{H}$?
2. $x\mapsto (\Phi,f(x))$ is smooth for all $\Phi$ in some dense subset?
3. $x\mapsto \|f(x)\|$ is smooth for all $\Phi\in\mathcal{H}$?
4. $x\mapsto \|f(x)\|$ is smooth for all $\Phi$ in some dense subset?

No 1. and 2. seem plausible to me, while 3. and 4. rather not.

Is there a concept of vector-valued Schwartz functions?

Maybe someone can point me towards sources on this topic.

Comment: In order to compute a derivative you can recur to Fréchet derivatives.

Comment: 3. and 4. are not even true for real-valued functions (think of functions with values in $\{\pm 1\}$).

Comment: I found 1. in "Espaces des functions différentiable a valeurs vectorielle" by Laurent Schwartz. Furthermore, he shows that $(\Phi,f(x))\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)~\forall \Phi\in\mathcal{H}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f(x)\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{H})$. The question now is whether this implies 2.